# Visual Studio 2022 turn off grey suggestions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

How does one turn off grey suggestions in Visual Studio 2022, but keep the table below?

[image: Grey suggestions]

Comment: Thank you for asking! This is the most horrendous thing added to VS2022. It would be OK if it **didn't always suggest the exact wrong code to add**!

Answer (score 26):

Depending on used version of VS 2022 (mine is 17.0.1, not preview), you can go to **Tools->Options->IntelliCode** and disable **Show completions for whole lines of code** option
[image]

Another option can be found in [Controlling Whole line completions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/visual-studio-whole-line-completions#controlling-whole-line-completions) docs
[image]

Just use small button near **Zoom** drop-down in the left bottom corner of main editor

Comment: If only there were an all-or-nothing switch in 2022. CodeLens has one.

Comment: Same with me, I would like to have a single switch to turn it off completely.

Comment: +1 For a single point to turn off. Very annoying if you are a long time resharper user and upgrade vs. You never quite know where vs ends and r# begins. If you are already using a professional grade analysis tool vs should at least ask you if you want to watch the two fight each other.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable that "IntelliCode Code Completions" feature in Visual Studio 2022 by going to  `Tools ==> Options ==> Preview Features` and uncheck `Enable all  IntelliCode preview features`

[image]

See: [Visual Studio IntelliCode Whole line completions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/visual-studio-whole-line-completions)

See also: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/intellicode/

> Note: We have several Preview features which are off by default and
> can be enabled through the Tools > Options > IntelliCode page.

Comment: Thank God. The dumb program seems like it wasn't even tested. Several easy to fix dumb suggestions have been driving me up a wall.