Disable suggested completions in Visual Studio 2022 and C#
I recently started learning C#, and I'm using Visual Studio 2022. I want to disable the contextual auto-completion (the gray text suggestions), but I don't want to disable the intellisense menu that suggests reserved keywords and other completions.
I've tried disabling various settings in intellicode, but nothing seems to work! Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you!

why n ot simply ignore it and tyoe yourself

Have you tried ignoring them. It's what I do. I don't even notice them anymore.

Have you checked this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011719/visual-studio-2022-turn-off-grey-suggestions ?

Just open Visual Studio Installer, uncheck 'Intellicode' in 'Individual components' tab and click 'Modify' to disable the auto-completion feature.
